# Acer TravelMate 8573T freezes when trying to install OS

Tags: operating-systems, windows-installer, acer-travelmate

In an effort to upgrade from windows 7 to Windows 10, I went to buy one of Microsofts USB flash drives with a Windows 10 installer and a product key. I inserted the flash drive, booted to it, and started the setup. It asked my language, keyboard, preferred architecture and product key.
 Everything fine, until the point were it should start the install. The screen froze at the step "Copying Windows files (0%)", and I was unable to move my mouse. I left it for over an hour and a half, but nothing had changed. I have by now tried to install:

- Windows 10 Pro (64 bit) from a Microsoft flash drive
- Windows 10 Pro (32 bit) from a Microsoft flash drive
- Windows 10 Home (64 bit) from a Microsoft flash drive
- Windows 10 Home (32 bit) from a Microsoft flash drive
- Windows 10 Pro (64 bit) from a self made flash drive installer
- Windows 10 Pro (32 bit) from a self made flash drive installer
- Windows 10 Home (64 bit) from a self made flash drive installer
- Windows 8.1 (64 bit) from a self made flash drive installer
- Ubuntu 20.4 LTS from a self made flash drive installer

I've even tried to put in 8 Gb of RAM (in stead of 4), but still all the Windows installers get stuck at the same point, and the Ubuntu installer get's stuck at a loading icon, right after scanning my hard drive.
I have an Acer TravelMate 8573T with an Intel Core i5 2430M, WDC 256 HHD, 4Gb of RAM and a BIOS in version 1.13. I have a graphics card (128Mb) as well, but since I can't gt an OS installed, I wouldn't know how to find out which graphics card that is (can't find it in the BIOS).
Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this? All ideas are welcome!!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is not a new machine. The most recent BIOS (8 years ago) is 1.22 . Try that.  https://www.acer.com/ac/en/ID/content/support-product/3728;-;   It may not run Windows 10

Comment: @John I thought of that, but I don't think there is a way for me to update the BIOS without an OS. On Acers website I first have to choose my OS before I can download the BIOS update.

Comment: Download the new BIOS to a bootable USB or CD and update it that way. BIOS update CDs were common back then.

Comment: Acers BIOS updates contain a Windows version and a DOS version only. I tried creating a bootable USB with freeDOS and ran the .bat file from the DOS version, however the DOS version still included .exe files, so I still need a windows install to be able to run the DOS version...

Comment: I am not sure what you can do at this point. You may need to accept that the machine is too old to run Windows 10

Comment: The .bat & .exe under DOS folder should have been designed to run under DOS environment. What error did you get when you tried to run the .bat file meant for DOS? However, if DOS version of BIOS flasher did not work, you can try booting thru some third-party Windows Rescue disks based on Windows 8/10 PE e.g. Hiren Boot DVD and see if it boots Live Windows environment and then try the Windows version of BIOS update. This however assumes that you have a working computer to download the rescue disk ISO and create a suitable (Legacy/UEFI) bootable pen drive. Continued..

Comment: ..Continued.  However, BIOS update is somewhat risky and if something goes wrong you may end up with a non-bootable system.  Also using such rescue disks, if they have any portable apps that check the health of HDD, I suggest you first also check the HDD health. A small possibility could be that the disk has bad sectors causing the installation to hang when disk I/O fails. Another option is to try and check if you can do a clean install of Windows 7 again on the system. You may need to take backup of important data from C drive if that matters before you do so. Continued..

Comment: Continued..After Windows 7 installs and hopefully runs ok, then from within Windows 7 run the BIOS flasher meant for Windows.